# How to install emacs29 with X11 support?

Tags: linux, install, x11, exwm

After installing emacs 29 with `yay emacs29-git` now on `startx` I get:

> You are trying to run Emacs configured with the "pure-GTK" interface under the X Window System. That configuration is unsupported and will lead to sporadic crashes during transfer of large selection data. It will also lead to various problems with keyboard input.

Furthermore and probably even more important

> [EXWM] Not running under X environment

Does `yay emacs29-git` install emacs as terminal version only whereas I'd need GUI?

`(framep(selected-frame))` returns *pgtk*

Note: I'm not having these problems at all with regular emacs (28.2) `sudo pacman emacs` but alas I'm forced to try 29 due to other issues.

Using arch linux

Answer (score 4):

When you compile Emacs you have options for specifying which windowing system to use, if any.  In current versions of Emacs, the options are:

```
--with-x      use the X Window System
--with-pgtk   use GTK to support window systems other than X
--with-ns     use Nextstep (macOS Cocoa or GNUstep) windowing system. On by default on macOS.
--with-w32    use native MS Windows GUI in a Cygwin build
```

The `pgtk` ("Pure GTK") option is intended for people running things like Wayland *instead of* X (and notably not "as well as X"; if you have X at all, pgtk is not recommended); so apparently `yay emacs29-git` is only meant for use by people who do not have X and you'll need to install Emacs 29 some other way (from a source which built it with X Window support).

As there's no stable release version of Emacs 29 yet, there probably aren't too many OS package options around.  It's pretty typical for users to compile such pre-release versions of Emacs themselves, so you might consider learning how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the other answer you may consider to install Emacs 29 from source.

I have installed Emacs 29 from source with X-support on Linux Mint 21 Cinnamon two days ago.

(framep(selected-frame)) returns x

Here are my documentation of the process which maybe work the same way also on other Linux versions.

Install git if it is not available on your system by default, then:

```
  ~ $ git clone --depth 1 --branch emacs-29 https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/emacs.git
#  clones into the directory  emacs  in the current directory which 
#    I have then renamed to:
  ~ $ cd /A/su/txtEditors/emacs/emacs-29.0.60_git-clone
#    and archived in an  emacs-29.0.60_git-clone.tar.xz  archive

#  there is no file  configure  in this directory but  autogen.sh  which 
#    will create it:   
  ~ $ ./autogen.sh  

#    in order to enable  imagemagick  installed various  -dev  files.

#  the standard value is --with-x-toolkit=gtk  but I want the athena 
#    toolkit (i.e. lucid) recommended as more stable than gtk: 
  ~ $ ./configure --with-x-toolkit=athena --with-imagemagick
#                                 =athena  =yes  are same as =lucid
#    not using --with-native-compilation=yes (=yes or empty)
  
#  ./configure is missing the  libacl   (not an error) and because the
#    ~ $ apt install libacl1
#    libacl1  was already installed it was necessary only to: 
  ~ $ apt install libacl1-dev

#  compile the C and elisp files: 
  ~ $ make

#  install the binary in /usr/local/bin: 
  ~ $ sudo make install

#  delete object and executable files: 
  ~ $ make clean
#                    along with the files created by ./configure: 
  ~ $ make distclean

#  change the look of the Emacs menu ( for:  ~ $ emacs -q &  )
#    by creating a new file: 
    ~/.Xdefaults
#    with following content:
Emacs.pane.menubar.background: SeaGreen
Emacs.pane.menubar.foreground: black
Emacs*shadowThickness: 1
#    and running: 
  ~ $ xrdb -merge ~/.Xdefaults
```

to install it with X support yourself (default is gtk).

Depending on your system you will maybe need to download some other packages and their development versions. See the output of ./configure for hints which ones and then check with Synaptic Package Manager or other package management app with search function the actual names you have to use to install them as they can differ from these you see in the ./configure output.